# Hi,i've been trying to reslove but couldn't do it and i'm using GIT from scratch total before i've know some basic commands

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push from my local to remote then this is what i'm encounterting everytime.

To https://github.com/Sriteja-ditcom/denoprac.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Sriteja-ditcom/denoprac.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 0):

Try `git pull` first 
Your local changes are older than the version on github